# Upload and share image on Google+

Tags: google-plus

I can't seem to find any documentation or reference on upload and sharing images on Google+.

Is this action current supported in google+?

Their [moment sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types) seems to accept thumbnail url, but I don't want to keep the image hosted on my site once it is created and shared by visitor.

Comment: If you were able to find a resolution on your own, would you please post the solution for the rest of us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few different options, but I'm not sure any of them are really what you're looking for.

Google+ doesn't really allow outside apps to upload and share something automatically.

As you've observed, the closest you can get is generating a Moment for them to share. And while there are similarities to Instant Upload, it isn't identical. You could probably use a [data url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to encode and store the image as part of the moment, but I haven't tested this.

Another alternative is to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to store the image in their Drive space, permit the image to be read publicly, get a link for it, and use this link as the thumbnail URL. Similarly, you might be able to use the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) to store the image. Both have good, but different, integration with Google+. The former is more modern, while the latter has more features that are tailored for images.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I will explore the Picasa album data api.